# suppressing Console Writes in a c# Console App (from other components)

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple console app that writes out status of various resources in a nicely formatted way.

This app is using some 3rd party components to connect to places.

Those components unfortunately do a lot Console.Writes (or some sort of logging) which all ends up intertwined with my messages.

I tried redirecting Console output (in hopes that i could filter non-mine messages), but that seems to work ONLY on my messages.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
Console.SetOut(tw);
```

So this works in redirecting console writes, but only on the ones i did.. output from 3rd party components is still streaming to my screen.. any other ways to supress that?

Comment: Are you starting the other processes yourself?

Comment: yes, just f5 from VS for now

Comment: I mean is there something like `Process MyThirdPartyComponent = new Process();` in your code?

Comment: nope, nothing like that. just calling some methods on a component that connects to a queue.. such as GetQueueDepth

Comment: Any chance there is some way of configuring the 3rd party tool to just not write it's logging.  I would hope that a professional level tool has that ability.  Possibly check their documentation or support tool.

Comment: I have a possible solution but it's not pretty :-)

Comment: i don't see a way to configure it.. in fact, all the output happens in the constructor of the object

Comment: Open your own `cmd.exe` and redirect your output there?

Comment: The 3rd party code is surely writing its own console output.  *Not* by using Console.Write() but by directly calling native console output functions.  Like printf() in code written in C.  You are probably seeing their debug trace.  You'll need to give them a call.

Comment: @SonicSoul Do the third party components have config files? Maybe there is a really simple solution you're overlooking. If the components are well made they'll have settings there you can probably change.

Comment: i can get the source code for those components, so i can take a look there. I was hoping to have a 10 min workaround since this is just a utility that's not any official tool i am working on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, there doesn't seem to be a reasonable quick way to suppress these, I went with plan B, that is deferring my messages to the end. This way all the logging gets through, and than i write out all the information i am interested in.

I broke it down into Success/Warn/Error methods

```
    public static void WriteError(string message, params string[] args) {
        writerTasks.Add(() => {
            var c = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(message, args);
            Console.ForegroundColor = c;
        });
    }
```

and at the end of the execution, i call this method to flush it out.

```
    private static void WriteResults() {
        foreach (var t in writerTasks)
            t();
    }
```

i do it this way, because i am changing text color depending on message type, which is contained within each action.

in my case this works great, since the information scrolls up hiding all the logging.. which in fact is also beneficial.. just didn't want it dispersed between the main output

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not able to redirect the output of the third party components is because you're calling redirect on your process, not theirs. To do this, loop over the processes, find the ones that are writing to the console and redirect their output.

```
 using System.Diagnostics;

 Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();


 foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
       // you'll actually need to use something like the process name or id here.
       if (theprocess == MyThirdPartyComponentsProcess)
       {
             theprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
             theprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
        }
  }
```

You'll have to be running as administrator for this work.

Comment: this is a cool idea, but i see one problem. When do i loop through the processes? This output happens in a constructor of the object i am using.. So When would this process kick in? before the constructor is called? because i am not sure if that process would exist yet ? and after the constructor is too late..

Comment: @SonicSoul Yeah that occurred to me. You'll have to monitor the running processes while executing your application. If they start when your application starts, then you can do this at the beginning of execution. If are only alive at the time you call the method then this probably won't work.

Comment: actually, this technique appears to see other processes running on my machine.. the 3rd party component is just a dll i am using in my app.. it's not a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of one fairly hacky way:

- Capture the existing `Console.Out` so you can reuse it in your "real" writer
- Create your own `TextWriter` implementation, which...
- ... when it's asked to write, checks whether the calling code is in your assembly. See [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx)

So long as you don't have inlining problems, you should be able to check the context, and drop any output you don't want. You'd probably have to call `Console.Out.WriteLine` directly instead of `Console.WriteLine`, mind you - otherwise the caller will be the `Console` class.

A *better* solution would be to change your code to use log4net or something similar, so you could get your output in a more configurable way, not on the console - assuming your own use is also logging. (If it's for interactive output, something like the above may be the only way...)

Comment: this is what i attempted. but the "capture the existing Console.Out" part appears to work only on my own writes.. not the 3rd party

Comment: @SonicSoul: Oh, I see. I misread the question. That's very strange. Are you doing it right at the start of the program?

Comment: yes, and the writes happen when calling a constructor of the class i am instantiating later in code

Comment: I am wondering if there is a more low level way to capture/redirect console writes than Console.SetOut